# Code need to split string AND remove unwanted characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

I have a page which receives a list of dates in the following format via ajax:

> ["2015-06-02T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-03T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-04T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-05T23:00:00.000Z"]

I have written the following code to split the dates out:

```
string input;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
        input = reader.ReadToEnd();
} 
string [] arr = input.Split(new string[] {","},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

but i need to remove the "T23:00:00.000Z" from each date. Can anyone assist?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to parse the `DateTime` after deserializing json.

Comment: Why? You can parse the date including the time offset just as easily...

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned that i need just the date element of each list item, not the time. I am not currently deserializing the JSON, but instead requesting the input stream (code above updated). Is this not the most efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string [] arr = input.Replace("T23:00:00.000Z","").Split(new string[] {","},StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a JSON array of dates. In which case using Json.NET you could just do:

```
DateTime[] dates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime[]>(*date array string*);
```

You're then free to do what you want with the new date array.

Answer (score 1):

Its look like json array of dates. Try to deserialize it with JSON.NET library (can found it in NuGet):

```
var jsonString = "["2015-06-02T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-03T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-04T23:00:00.000Z","2015-06-05T23:00:00.000Z"]";
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<DateTime[]>(jsonString);
```